# Query inner collection using Entity Framework

Tags: linq, entity-framework

I have an object Employee

```
public class Employee
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public ICollection<Address> addresses {get;set;}
}

public class Address
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string AddressLine1 {get;set;}
    public string City {get;set;}
}
```

Now the `Employee` is a part of my context.

How do I query the employee object where the `address.city` is "NY"? I want to traverse to the `Address` collection from the `Employee` object in the context.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try with this

```
MyDBContext.Employee.Where(e => e.Addresses.Any(a => a.city == "NY").ToList();
```

with this code you will get all Employees, for whom at least one of the address is in New york. If you want that all address of Employee be in New Yowk, then change `Any` for `All`.